# How does one receive messages from a stream?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I've been looking around for the answer without luck. The program is a simple chat app that either listens or talks. The connection is established between the client and server, but when I send a message, the other does not seem to recieve it.

server waiting for connection

```
private void ListenForConnection(IPAddress ipAddress)
{

    tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, portNumber);
    tcpListener.Start();

    client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    stream = client.GetStream();

    stream.ReadTimeout = 200;

}
```

client connecting

```
private void EstablishConnection(IPAddress ipAddress)
{

    client = new TcpClient();

    client.Connect(ipAddress, portNumber);

    stream = client.GetStream();

    stream.ReadTimeout = 200;

}
```

client writing a message

```
 public void SendMessage(String message)
    {
        StreamWriter networkWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

        networkWriter.Write(message);

        networkWriter.Flush();

    }
```

server reading a message

```
public String ListenForMessage()
    {

        String networkRead = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            networkRead = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        return networkRead;

    }
```

The send and recieve are identical for server and client. I intend to add error handling more when the messages are working.

I'm wondering that possibly there is an issue with my connection. Currently I am running 2 instances of the chat program on my machine, one server one client. The client connects at 127.0.0.1 (localhost) on port 8080 when the server is listening to port 8080. However the client does not connect at 192.168.1.100, which is my computer's actual ip, not sure if that might indicate something.

EDIT: adjusted the write and read to use stream writer and reader and flush

Comment: You need to learn about networking. `TcpClient`, and TCP/IP in general, operates on streams of bytes. If you want to impose a message structure on this, then you have to do it yourself. Like, maybe precede each message with the number of bytes in the message. The client would read the number of bytes, then read the next "n" bytes as the message.

Comment: @Saunders I've also tried using StreamReader and StreamWriter because that seems to have the message structure iposed, but I haven't had any luck

Comment: There is no message structure unless you impose it.

Comment: Also, get rid of those try/catch blocks. If something goes wrong, you need to know about it. Also, your `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` need to be in `using` blocks: `using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)){return reader.ReadToEnd();}`

Comment: The reason for the try catch is that the listener is trigered regularly without knowing if there will be something there or not, I set the readTimeout so that the program wont stall on trying to read when there is nothing to read, and the try/catch lets the program continue through a readtimeout

Comment: That's a bad practice. If you want to catch timeouts, then `catch (TimeoutException e)` or something. Do not catch and then ignore all exceptions

Comment: `However the client does not connect at 192.168.1.100, which is my computer's actual ip` <-- check if firewall is active and blocking the port.

Answer (score 1):

1.First of all , I will suggest you to make sure that your connection has been really established between your client and server.
2.Secondly, I will suggest you to flush your stream after you write, there are cache mechanism built in Stream, write to stream doesn't mean it will be send across the wire immediately.
3.It is a good way to learn networking in this way, but if you are creating commercial product, I will suggest you to look for some mature open source components.

Comment: (First off this is for learning purposes and not commercial), I think the connection is being established because tcp listener waits until a connection is made before progressing through the code. the code does progress, so I think the connection is ok.

Comment: also, I tried adding stream.flush() after writing without success

Comment: Can you post your project somewhere, so we can help you to have a look.

Comment: Where would you suggest I post it?

Comment: If you like I can e-mail it

Comment: Send it to me , happy to help

Comment: It seems your e-mail isn't shown on you profile, is it set to private?

Comment: Maybe put your e-mail address in your 'about you' for a little so I can send?